# Open links in new tab in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, xul

I am developing an Firefox extension. How can all the links on a webpage to be opened in a new tab?

Comment: What if the default behavior is to open a new window?

Comment: then he can only have it do that - the user's configs will override what his extension chooses, for obvious and sensible reasons.

Answer (score 4):

That's usually a configurable option in Firefox  to handle new links, so they may override your extension with that.

However...

The code

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/"> Example Website</a>
```

will allow you to click the appearing words [Example Website], and the link will open in the current window.

The code

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/" target="_blank"> Example Website</a>
```

Opens the link in a new window/tab.

The only mildly dodgy thing is that target is now apparently deprecated by the W3C, which means that it's generally up to the browser ( and the user's preferences) as to how (or even if) it is handled.  But for people who have their preferences set accordingly - in **Firefox** - that should work.

Answer (score 1):

I found what I was after. I wanted **gbrowser.addtab(this.href)**.

Answer (score -3):

Press Ctrl while clicking on the link on Windows. Use cmd on OSX.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Firefox extensions can't press keys on the keyboard (unless hooked into something like a USB robot!)

Comment: or press the scroll button on your mouse

Comment: It's not that he wants to do it as a user - he wants code in his extension that does it as part of the app...

Comment: Thank you all but u guys are not hitting the chord... you know what i mean... like in greasemonkey u can open a given link on any webpage (not a website hosted by me) any general one... So in greasemonkey i can do the following:

link.addEventListener('click',function(e){     
                                         e.stopPropagation();
                                         e.preventDefault();
                                        GM_openInTab(this.href);
},false);

Would anyone know a code equivalent to this for extension developement?

Comment: Ok, I think you are very close! Just check out this pages: http://tools.w3clubs.com/ext/    http://ted.mielczarek.org/code/mozilla/extensiondev/